# Subtract DateTime in this format

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

```
C2 = Start date = 9/16/2018 12:41:02
B2 = End date = 9/18/2018 15:37:12
```

Using 24 hour format

Tried using `=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(C2,8))-TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(B2,8))`, it wouldn't work when the result supposed to be over 1 day

Expected results = `2 days 02:56:10`

Is it possible to subtract this in Excel?

I want it to be `=C2-B2`

[image: Expected result]

Comment: There is no Excel format for a period length which contains days part. You may use format `[h]:mm:ss` which will give you the result `50:56:10`. If you want to create the output directly as shown you must write your own formatting function. It will have 'string' data type.

Comment: Hi @Akina Thanks for commenting, i have tried `[h]:mm:ss`, but it shows me `#Value!`  , i just use the formula of `=B2-C2`

Comment: Is your source data a datetime or it is a string? What value is shown if do not specify the cell format?

Comment: @Akina
i downloaded the file from some party.
I think it is shows as string, not datetime, because the format is `General`
I have edited the descriptions, the image is included

Comment: If so you must convert string type data to datetime type, and then calculate.

Comment: @Akina i have a previous version file, which is `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format `General` and i can subtract timing for 2 cells, and shows me the expected result
and the new versions is `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format `General` and i can't subtract

Comment: *the new versions is mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format General and i can't subtract* Conver it to a previous format by common string functions. It allow Excel autoconvert the data from string to datetime, so you'll can perform calculations again.

Comment: @Akina i have tried by convert it to date/time by using `=TEXT(B2,"MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss")` , and try using `=E2-D2` it still shows me `#value!`

Comment: What kind of a file?  If it is a text or csv file, you should **import** the file and designate the date column in the import as having the format existing in the csv/text file.  Excel will then convert the value to a "regular" Excel date, and you will be able to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
=INT(C2-C1)&" days  " & TEXT(C2-C1, "h"" hrs ""m"" mints """)
```

**How it works:**

- TEXT function in this formula applies a custom 
  number format for `Hours and Minutes` to a 
  value created by subtracting the `End Date` 
  from the `Start Date`.
- INT function,strips off the integer 
  portion of the `End Date`, `minus` the `Start 
  Date`.

*if you have many values as `End & Start Dates` 
 then this formula can be used.*

```
=INT(SUMPRODUCT(C5:C9-B5:B9))&" days "&TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(C5:C9-B5:B9),"h"" hrs ""m"" mins """)
```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Hi, i think the value in the field you used is different from mine, for more information, i have 10k data that has the format i wrote in the descriptions above
the date is `9/16/2018` but not `9/16/18`, and its in a `24 hours` format for time.

Comment: @NeverLucky, I've also used `24 Hrs Date Time` Format for that values I've used n the example that's the reason `15:37` reflects in my example as `3:37 PM`. If you have range of `Dates` then use the 2nd example `SUMPRODUCT`. Both the formulas I've shown are working with 100%   accuracy since   it's been tested.☺

Comment: @NeverLucky, the cell formats are `MM/DD/YY  HH:MM AM/PM` that's why is shows `09/16/18`, otherwise the actual date is `09/06/2018`, you can change it to `DD/MM/YYYY  HH:MM AM/PM` !! ☺ Since my formula are working properly that's the reason our results are similar. ! ☺

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately, it still doesn't work for my file, feel so weird, suppose it should work with normal `=B2-C2`, this is cracking my head, btw, thanks ~

Comment: @NeverLucky, i'ts really unfortunate that You have been failed to reproduce it. the formula is in Cell `C4` and the Screen shot is part of my worksheet. Just do it again ! Write  what  the formula returns any Error or the wrong answer ??

Comment: it returns #value! 
i have tested by ammending the date to dd/mm/yyyy then i can use normal subtractions `=C2-B2`
`=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(C2,8))-TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(B2,8))` i have used this formula before, and it can return correct value, but only for date/time that is within 1 day, is it possible to amend this, and make it able to calculate even more than 1 day?

Comment: @NeverLucky,  find my mail Id in profile & just mail the File, I'll check & correct it ☺

Comment: Thanks~ i have emailed you, we will chat in the e-mail then, if found any solutions only we post it up here~ Cheers

Comment: @NeverLucky,, soon I'll return the file through mail give me some time. ☺

Answer (score 0):

So i have look for some help and able to get the answer,
it can't subtract as the format that i exported out is not recognized by excel
So i used this formula to convert all the cell into Date/Time with `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS` from `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS`

`=IF(ISERR(VALUE(MID(B2,3,2))),IF(ISERR(VALUE(MID(B2,3,1))),IF(ISERR(VALUE(MID(B2,4,2))),VALUE(MID(B2,4,1)),VALUE(MID(B2,4,2))),VALUE(MID(B2,3,1))),VALUE(MID(B2,3,2)))&"/"&IF(ISERR(VALUE(LEFT(B2,2))),VALUE(LEFT(B2,1)),VALUE(LEFT(B2,2)))&"/"&MID(B2,LEN(B2)-12,4)&" "&RIGHT(B2,8)`

and able to use subtractions after that~

Would welcome for more simple answer for doing this.

Thanks for those who provided solutions for my questions.